# How to make split() case insensitive

Tags: javascript

I want to split on `Red` and `red`. How can I make split case insensitive?

```
const str = "my Red balloon"
const searchTxt = "red"
const strArr = str.split(searchTxt);
```

I've tried variations of

```
const strArr = str.split(/searchTxt/gi);
```

Comment: in the above example, `searchText` is lowercase but I can't make the `str` lowercase

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the **[RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor**  with the desired flags as second  argument

`RegExp(expression, flags)`

**Important:** when passing arbitrary strings (like from a user input) to the RegExp constructor - make always sure to
**escape RegExp special characters** the `RegExp` might confuse as regular expression **tokens** such as `.` *(*any character*)* `?` *(*one or more*)* etc, etc.  See the two link-demos below.

```js
const str = "my Red balloon"
const searchTxt = "red"
const regEscape = v => v.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&');
const strArr = str.split(new RegExp(regEscape(searchTxt), "ig"));
console.log(strArr)
```

- [Example with **wrong** output **without escaping**](https://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/csafr7n9/)
- [Example with **correct** output **with escaping**](https://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/csafr7n9/1/)

Comment: What is the benefit of escaping the special charectors?

Comment: @Bill in case the search string is i.e: `ed?` the `?` will be treated as `?` Regular Expression **Zero or One** character, instead of Question mark - therefore you **always need to escape the characters** that come from a user input into the `RegExp` constructor.

Comment: @Bill You can use String.raw`\d\d` to avoid using '\\d\\d'.

Comment: @Bill see this jsfiddle example to understand what happens is you don't escape special RegExp characters: https://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/csafr7n9/ - the output is clearly not the desired one. While here instead that's fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/csafr7n9/1/ and returns the expected split.

Answer (score 5):

In order to use a variable in a regular expression, you need to use the RegExp constructor. No need to use the `g` flag, since `split` will always look for all occurrences:

```js
const str = "my Red balloon"
const searchTxt = "red"
const strArr = str.split( new RegExp(searchTxt, 'i') );
console.log(strArr);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a `RegExp()` like this:

```
var str = "my Red balloon"
var searchTxt = "red"
var rgx = RegExp(searchTxt, "gi");
var strArr = str.split(rgx);
```

This is because you can't simply use the `/searchTxt/gi` method because it will read it as a string (so it's going to get split where it matches "searchTxt", as a string and not as a variable).

Comment: This doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

This is the right way

```
const str = "my Red balloon";
var arr = str.split(/red/i);
```

Comment: This way you're changing the original string

Comment: The problem is not that I'm changing the original string, but that doesn't split case insensitive as request in the question. I don't know what I wrote and why, probably I was pissed...I edited the answer, now is right